# Get Results from zxing - directly integrated in Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

im new to all the programming stuff so please forgive me If my question is rather stupid ;)

I integrated zxing directly as a library and now im trying to scan some QR Codes and get the result. But sadly I have no idea how to get it.

I found some hints that it works with "onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) "and for that i have to declare a new intent like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But if I copy this code to my app, it will always try to open a thirdparty app. Thats exactly what i dont want. 
Im sure my mistake is very obvious, but I dont see it ;) Would be happy about every help.

Comment: Please write your own scanning application, with its own UI and Manifest declarations. You are not intended to "natively" integrate our app. You can reuse the core scanning and bits of the Barcode Scanner app. Don't copy and paste please.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not getting you wrong, you want to display ZXing natively.
To do that please follow this tutorial

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

In case of any doubt please let me know.
Regards.

Comment: As I've explained a hundred times across the internet, this is discouraged. It's not discouraged if you do it right, such that it doesn't harm our app (i.e. not copying the UI and Manifest), but "helpful" tutorials like this are usually helping people do the thing that is quickest and most profitable, which does not include doing it right. The advice here is not OK with the developers.